# “Like” option in News feed is missing (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, feed

I have a news feed web part in my home page. But, for some reason the "Like" option is missing and I cant find where to put this back.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2629e8f6-f32a-4eb5-a4a9-6b097bcc8835/i-like-it-button-is-missing?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: This worked for me:

[link] http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142418/like-option-in-news-feed-is-missing/142464#142464